# Изменение $view для метода render в Controller Yii 1.x - есть ли более правильное решение?

Tags: php, yii, controller, render

В Yii 1.x нужно менять view-файлы, если в `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` встречается слово: `MobBrowser` к примеру.

В файле `protected/components/Controller.php` я добавил:

```
class Controller extends CController
{

    public function render($view,$data=null,$return=false)
    {
        if ($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']=='MobBrowser')
             $view = 'm_' . $view;
        return parent::render($view,$data=null,$return=false);
    }
}
```

Всё работает, но может как-то более правильно можно было это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Вместо `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` можно воспользоваться `Yii::app()->request->getUserAgent()`, там уже проверяется существует ли индекс `HTTP_USER_AGENT` в запросе, а то если его не будет в данном примере, вылетит неприятный Notice.

2) Возвращай просто `return parent::render($view, $data, $return)`, без назначения переменным других значений, а то у тебя `$data` и `$return` всегда будут `null` и `false` соответственно, не зависимо, что ты передашь в метод `render()`.

```
class Controller extends CController
{

    public function render($view, $data = null, $return = false)
    {
        if (Yii::app()->request->getUserAgent() == 'MobBrowser') {
             $view = 'm_' . $view;
        }

        return parent::render($view, $data, $return);
    }
}
```

3) Для последующего удобного расширения способа проверки мобильного браузера и его внедрения в другие части кода, стоит создать отдельный метод в некой общей модели/хелпере.